# APK Size increased dramatically with appcompat-v7:23.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-appcompat

My APK size was around 11 MB last week with appcompat-v7:23.2.0.

Last week I've updated my SDK and changed my App compact version in gradle file eventually from 23.2.0 to 23.4.0 and all of a sudden my APK size gone up to 20 MB.

I've unzipped both APK's and found that drawable files of V4 has been increased with my latest APK.

With 23.2.0

[image: With 23.2.0]

With 23.4.0

[image]

Is there is any way around to reduce the size ofAPK?

EDIT 1:

FYI : I have added following code in my gradle.

`buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your gradle.build file inside your app module.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

The skrinkResources will remove unused drawables.